# How to preventDefault from external function and not in the event Listener?

Tags: javascript

I have this event listener, to submit a form.

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#form input');
    
    // Check for empty fields
    if ([...inputs].some(input => !input.value)) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submitted until all fields are not empty
    }
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        
        // Validate specific inputs - where "name" starts with "actual-temp"
        if(inputs[i].name.startsWith("actual-temp")) {
            validateActualTemp(inputs[i].value, inputs[i]); // This is another function to check values
        }
    }
        
});
```

And after this event Listener I have this function:

```
function validateActualTemp(value, item) {
    if(value === '10') {
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

This validates input fields - and checks if the number is shown. What I need to do now is, if the `value === '10'` then stop submitting the form, even if the fields are all filled out.

I have tried this:

```
function validateActualTemp(value, item) {
    if(value === '10') {
        preventDefault();
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

But it is not working - How can I `preventDefault();` in an external function?

Comment: Return a value from the function and check the value inside the listener, eg return false if it isnt valid and if your function returns false run `preventDefault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the event to the other function:

```js
//...
validateActualTemp(inputs[i].value,inputs[i],e)
//...


function validateActualTemp(value, item,e) {
    if(value === '10') {
        e.preventDefault();
        item.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        console.log(item);
    }
}
```

Or return true/false from your validation function and handle everything else in the event handler callback.

Comment: It worked, when I tried this it didn't work. Must of miss-typed something.

Comment: :) perfect Happy coding